Can't access phpmyadmin on nginx
I am trying to have "/phpmyadmin" on my website. I am using nginx as a reverse proxy, fastapi with guvicorn on the backend, and MySQL. OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4
I can't seem to find any info on how to setup phpmyadmin WITHOUT PHP. Is it even possible? Or should I use something else as a database management system on the web?
Here is my nginx website config located at /etc/nginx/sites-available/picour.ru
server {
    server_name picour.ru www.picour.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/picour.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/picour.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.picour.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = picour.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name picour.ru www.picour.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


Being that phpmyadmin is written in php, you will need a php server to run it.
